# Sending Blob data with WebRTC Data Streams

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm reading the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample

In this example, they are sending simple strings over the data channel:

```
var message = messageInputBox.value;
sendChannel.send(message);
```

I am trying to send a blob:

[image]

However on the receiving connection, I get no data:

[image]

Why is this happening?  How do I properly serialize a `Blob` and send it over an `RTCDataConnection`?  My target browsers are latest Chrome only, in case it matters.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Example_for_extracting_data_from_a_Blob) shows how to get raw data from a Blob as a TypedArray, which is a serializable format.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts nice - any pointers RE converting `reader.result` back into a `Blob` on the receiver end?

Comment: `new Blob([reader.result], { type: "mimetype/here" })`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you!!  Is any additional configuration needed to get `JSON.stringify` to serialize a `TypedArray`?  I'm seeing the same behavior despite converting the `Blob`.

Comment: You don't use `JSON.stringify()`. TypedArrays can't be serialized as JSON, they should be in a binary format.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok - the data is now transmitting.  How would you recommend attaching some metadata to this `ArrayBuffer` given that I can't stringify it in an object?

Comment: That's probably worthy of another question. You'd most likely have to use a 3rd party library to convert the typed array into an image object format, then generate a new typed array from the updated object. I don't know any library that does this off the top of my head, but I can check it out for you later.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - awesome thanks.  I'll post another question - want me to delete this or do you want to post your comments as an answer?

Comment: I'll post as an answer once I have more time. Please do not delete this, as this will be useful for future readers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - you got it.  ArrayBuffer question up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835322/transmitting-an-arraybuffer-with-metadata-over-a-webrtc-data-connection  Thank you again